# SSRS : Display a text instead of a value

Tags: reporting-services

I have a problem at the moment. I can't do what I want in my Reporting Service.

I have different serial number data coming to me. As they are serial numbers, they are never the same numbers. However, in two specific cases, we have the same serial number :

Number 1 = Test device
No data = Still in production

I would therefore like the number 1 in my service reporting column to read "Device under test" instead of "Device under test" and, when there is no value, to write "Still in production".

Basically, the column should look like this:

- 438834865358
- 435834582523
- 523252352352
- STILL IN PRODUCTION
- 34563434664343
- 34634643663462
- DEVICE UNDER TEST
- 34553454595435

Can you help me please ?

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with an expression. However, this will force the column to become a string rather than a number.

```
<expression> = IIF(IsNothing(Fields!SerialNumber.Value),"STILL IN PRODUCTION",
                   IIF(Fields!SerialNumber.Value = 1, "DEVICE UNDER TEST", 
                       Fields!SerialNumber.Value))
```